# How to add a DropDown widget in an Overlay Window

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, overlay

I'm trying to implement an overlay containing a TextFormField on top of a screen when an Inkwell is pressed. The overlay is also setup as a global so that I can be able to call in from any other screen and pass different widgets into it depending on use case.

So basically I have 3 screens, the main.dart, unit_screen.dart, overlay_screen.dart as shown below:

On main.dart I create the overlay instance as a global

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: homeRoute,
      title: '',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.grey[450], primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey
      ),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Overlay(
            initialEntries: [
              OverlayEntry(
                builder: (context) {
                  // Create an instance of `OverlayScreen` to be accessed globally
                  overlayScreen = OverlayScreen.of(context);
                  return child ?? const SizedBox();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      
    );
  }
}
```

unit_screen.dart contains the Add Bill button that calls the overlay and passes the options list and textEditingController to overlayScreen

```
class UnitScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    UnitScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _UnitScreenState createState() => _UnitScreenState();
}

class _UnitScreenState extends State<UnitScreen> {
    List<String> options = ["Electricity", "Water", "Service", "Maintenance"];
    String? selectedOption;
    TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: InkWell(
                    splashColor: Colors.green,
                    onTap: () {
                        // display the overlay
                        overlayScreen?.show(selectedOption, amountController, options);
                    },
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.add),
                            Text("Add Bill"),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
           ),
        );
    }
}
```

overlay_screen.dart contains the overlay logic and widget

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverlayScreen {
  /// Create an Overlay on the screen
  /// Declared [overlay Entrys] as List<OverlayEntry> because we might have
  /// more than one Overlay on the screen, so we keep it on a list and remove all at once
  BuildContext _context;
  OverlayState? overlayState;
  List<OverlayEntry>? overlayEntrys;

  void closeAll() {
    for (final overlay in overlayEntrys ?? <OverlayEntry>[]) {
      overlay.remove();
    }
    overlayEntrys?.clear();
  }

  void show(selectedOption, amountController, options) {
    overlayEntrys?.add(
      OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) {
          return _buildOverlayWidget(context, selectedOption, amountController, options);
        },
      ),
    );

    overlayState?.insert(overlayEntrys!.last);
  }

  OverlayScreen._create(this._context) {
    overlayState = Overlay.of(_context);
    overlayEntrys = [];
  }

  factory OverlayScreen.of(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlayScreen._create(context);
  }

  Widget _buildOverlayWidget(context, selectedOption, amountController, options) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Center (
      child: Container(
        width: screenWidth * 0.8,
        height: screenHeight * 0.6,
        color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
        child: Material( // Wrap the Column with Material widget
          elevation: 8,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Add a Bill'),
                DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: selectedOption,
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                    //setState(() {
                      selectedOption = newValue;
                    //});
                  },
                  items: options.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: amountController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // removed all overlays on the screen
                        closeAll();
                      },
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Post button logic
                        final selectedAmount = amountController.text;
                        // Use 'selectedOption' and 'selectedAmount' to send data to HTTP
                        // Perform the HTTP request here
                      },
                      child: Text('Post'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: overlay displayed]

The overlay shows but the dropdown menu does not show the list. On tapping the dropdown the error:
"Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator." is shown on the Console.

How can this be solved?